# How can I correctly make this JavaScript to sort a table by the column I want?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

From what I've read, I think the main part I need to edit is the one below and the full script is at http://pastebay.net/1299761 
The webpage table can be seen at http://coursetorrent.stanford.edu:6969/ and the column I want to sort by default is Seeds.
(If you are a Freelancer please contact me.)

```
 var allspans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var ci=0;ci<allspans.length;ci++) {
    if (allspans[ci].className == 'sortarrow') {
        if (getParent(allspans[ci],"table") == getParent(lnk,"table")) { 
            allspans[ci].innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the webpage table the actual table you are attempting to sort, or are you using it as an example?

Comment: There is a lot more to it than this.  Sorting a table means moving rows.  All this code appears to do is remove the sort arrow from the previously sorted column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using this script:

Dynamic Table
http://dynamictable.com/

Sortable Table
http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/